# Spring Boot 2.1.2 Create dynamic DB connection just to run a query

Tags: sql-server, spring-boot, jdbc

In the Spring Boot 2.1.2 project, there is a default PostgreSQL db connection defined in application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://host:port/dbName
spring.datasource.username=username
spring.datasource.password=pass
```

Not any problem with Postgre DB, however, I need to connect another DB (MsSql) by JDBC connection rarely.
I just need to run a query, and process result list from a view of mssql table. 
What I tried is;

Adding jdbc drivers to Pom.xml for Mssql:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
    <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>7.2.1.jre11</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Connect to sql-server and run query:

```
@GetMapping(path = "/getKonteynersFromSifirAtikServis/", produces = "application/json")
public ResponseEntity<ResponseStatusDto> getKonteynersFromSifirAtikServis() {
    try {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://host:1433/msDbName");
        dataSource.setUsername("ms_user");
        dataSource.setPassword("ms_pass");

        JdbcTemplate template = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
        SqlRowSet sqlRowSet = template.queryForRowSet("SELECT * FROM dbo.viewName;");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        return new ResponseEntity<ResponseStatusDto>(ResponseStatusDto.createErrorDto(e.getMessage(), e), HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);
    }
}
```

This did not work. It throws:

```
Could not load JDBC driver class [com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver]
```

I have been getting hard to load **mssql-jdbc** inside pom definition. It is resolved to make version 7.2.1.jre11.

Comment: Try version 7.4.1.jre8

Comment: the scope of the dependency is set to test . Remove the same and try a run

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scope of the dependency is set as [test](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope).

> **test** This scope indicates that the dependency is not required for
>   normal use of the application, and is only available for the test
>   compilation and execution phases. This scope is not transitive.

Remove the same and attempt a run

Comment: God bless you! maven dependency is scoped test by default, and I did not realize it prevents to access on compile scope. Now, it can use driver, but, at this time, I am getting: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The port number 1433/DbName is not valid even I can get access by DBeaver with same settings. I have checked IntelliJ and Java services are enabled on firewall...

Comment: The connection URL used is of mysql format. From the details , I assume you are connecting to Microsoft SQL Server . Please check the following URL to identify the correct format : https://alvinalexander.com/java/jdbc-connection-string-mysql-postgresql-sqlserver.

Comment: db_url      = jdbc:microsoft:sqlserver://HOST:1433;DatabaseName=DATABASE

Comment: Ow.. you are right: jdbc:sqlserver://HOST:1433;databaseName=DBNAME works... Thank you.

Comment: Glad that I could help ! Happy New Year wishes to you